# Paypal Payment having access to form data

Tags: php, paypal, laravel-5

We are using paypal for purchases in our site and came across an issue with having access to form data after payment.

Here is the storyboard:

1. Choose an item to purchase
2. Pay with paypal
3. Paypal redirects to a controller action that no longer has access to original data

We have access to the SKU, the quantity purchased, but for example, if you were purchasing a private session on a certain date, how do we know what date he chose? We could use hacks to get around this but we want to know how to do it correctly.

Comment: You have to store these informations in your own DB. When a command is made, insert it. Then, pass ID through Paypal to know if payment is done.

Comment: Should I be making a 'queue' sort of table and then transfering the row on payment? We are already storing transaction information in our table - but did not think to preemptively add the purchase with the original form data